# What is considered a high but safe amount of D-mannose before causing kidney damage?

Tags: kidney, urinary-system, urinary-tract-infect-uti

I'm currently taking a product called: [Vibrant Health - U.T. Vibrance, Crisis Intervention Formula](https://shop.vibranthealth.com/products/ut-vibrance?variant=39324033646615), which suggests to take 5 grams of this product 4 times a day, so basically 20 grams a day for about 4 days. I got some digestive issues the next day after taking this product but I thought it was just fine, just a side effect of this product. I then was doing some research to see if it was still  OK to take that amount of D-mannose and surprisingly I found online that it says in many health pages that high doses of D-mannose [might damage the kidneys](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/d-mannose-uses-and-risks), so then I freaked out and I was trying to do my research to see what is considered a high dose on D-mannose. Good thing I have been taking this product for 2 days only.

I would think that if this product is being sold without prescription is safe to take that amount without having any permanent damage to the kidneys, but I would like to better be safe than sorry.

I couldn't find the answer so I just decided to ask here what is the maximum amount that would be considered safe for adults before it might cause kidney damage?

**NOTE**: I'm not looking for an advice on my condition, all I'm looking for is what is considered a high dose of D-Mannose, which many articles talk about but fail to specify what would be considered as a high dose. It says in many articles that a safe dose is between 1 and 3 grams a day, but they don't specify what would be considered a high dose. So it could be 10, 20, 30 gms a day maybe? That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: "I would think that if this product is being sold without prescription is safe to take" -- You misunderstand how supplements are regulated. It's a supplement, not a drug, so it's regulated more like food than medicine. Being non-prescription is absolutely no guarantee of safety.

Comment: I don't know why my question was closed, this is very frustrating because the reason of closing the question is that I'm looking for an advice on my condition and I'm not currently looking for that. I'm trying to find out what would be considered a high dose, which is not mentioned in any article online. It's a general question, no really looking for advise on my specific scenario.

Comment: Telling us you're taking a supplement and then asking us for safe dosing of that supplement most certainly is asking for personal medical advice. I'm sorry you're frustrated, but you should note that the industry that supplies you with that supplement has no answers for you. They probably can't even tell you exactly what's in it. So why aren't they doing studies to answer questions like yours? That's how it works in the pharmaceuticals business. You want to sell a drug? Prove it's safe and effective first. But they just skip that step by labelling it a supplement and selling it as food.

Comment: @CareyGregory Sorry but my question doesn't have anything to do with the supplement I'm taking. I just provided that information to give an introduction of why I'm asking that question. The question like I said in the NOTE: section, has to do with the GENERAL dose for D-Mannose (the ingredient), not the product itself, obviously nobody would be able to answer that question if I was asking about the product. I'm citing an article online because it says that high level doses of D-Mannose can be dangerous, all I'm asking is what's considered a high dose, or what would be the threshold.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to follow your logic. You're taking a supplement and you want to know the safe dosage, but somehow that has nothing to do with why you're asking. That's not credible.